# Sum transaction object using c#

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to create a new function to calculate and sum all the variants of the transactions.
As you can see I have few variants and their prices need to be summed.
Please assist me to calculate those figures.
I have the following code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Transaction tr = new Transaction();
    tr.AddVariant(new Variant(7, 2, "Bread", 10));
    tr.AddVariant(new Variant(5, 1, "Milk", 20));
    tr.AddVariant(new Variant(1, 10, "Tomato", 30));
    Variant v1 = new Variant(5, 6, "Cake", 40);
    Variant v = new Variant(5, 6, "Chocolate", 41);
    v.setChild(v1);
    tr.AddVariant(v);
}

public void AddVariant(Variant variant)
{
    VariantsList.Add(variant);
}
```

Comment: you should provide an example of your model so we can identify which property is the price

Comment: public class Variant
   {
    public Variant() { }
    public Variant(float Price,int Quantity, string Name, int Code) {
        this.Name = Name;
        this.Price = Price;
        this.Quantity = Quantity;
        this.Code = Code;
    }

Comment: please edit your question to include the code and also include your Transaction model

Answer (score 0):

Using Linq as @Daniel suggested, but considering the Quantity as well:

```
public decimal CalculateSum()
{
   return VariantList.Sum(x => x.Price * x.Quantity);
}
```